# Button doesn't work on a new thread

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-thread

Previously I had error - something about some loop, I've seen info that it is necessary in that case to start a new thread for button, but still nothing happens, thought logs show no errors now.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int CAPTURE = 9003;
    Button button;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.capture);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("BUTTON","CLICKED");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(CaptureActivity.AutoFocus, true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to write button.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("BUTTON","CLICKED");
                    }
                });

Comment: it seems from the code that you should be redirected directly to CaptureActivity.class as u have `startActivityForResult`call inside oncreate.. So there is no event firing on button seems possible..

Comment: @Dilip thanks for attention, but can't understand where exactly put it, would you mind to create an answer ?

Comment: you don't need this , no need to tell the OS to execute code on UI where it actually will be executed on UI and as @Cristian said you need to initialize context variable as well or use `MainActivity.this`

Comment: @Aalap Patel it seems you right, I put onClick into another class now at least I have flickering screen on button click.

Answer (score 1):

[`runOnUiThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) mean you are telling the UI thread to execute the passed `Runnable` as instruction so it won't create a new thread.

Solution : I assume you this code is for demo purpose for threading and UI updation so one of best alternative is to `AsyncTask`

and remove `runOnUiThread` function , no need of it

---

**You need to remove this code or move it inside run method**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(CaptureActivity.AutoFocus, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE);
```

Because you are currently in `CaptureActivity` not on `MainActivity`.
`OnCreate` will directly take you to the `CaptureActivity` where you are expecting the code of `MainActivity` to run (probably they have same UI)

Comment: I don't think he  needs an AsyncTask to handle a button click event though

Comment: @ZerO yeah but the suggested solution is to have threading via doInBackGround and execute UI work via `postexecute` which will work as a thread as well as UI updater

Comment: It seesm onClick() should have been in CaptureActivity class.

Comment: @AndyD that's your wish though as per the current code , i suggested as per the behavior your question asked for and still no need of `runOnUiThread` :)

Comment: @AndyD and why you would like to have `MainActivity` just to go to next activity without doing nothing, no need of it

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh you right, it's just left from previous version of my code.